# Pentaho PDI (Spoon): MySQL table output very slow (~2000 rows/s)

Tags: mysql, pentaho, kettle, pdi

My table output step is terribly slow (~2.000 rows/second), compared to the input (100.000-200.000 rows/second). The MySQL server is not the problem, using native MySQL, e.g. with the "Execute SQL script" step, I get something in the 100thousands/second. I already tried (without success) the common solution of extending the SQL options by:

```
useServerPrepStmts=false
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
useCompression=true
```

I also varied the commit size parameter (100, 1.000, 10.000) and `Use batch updates for inserts` is enabled, also without success. What else can I do? I have tables with ~10.000.000 rows and Pentaho runs on a very potent machine, so this is not acceptable.

Comment: Are you using any filters in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

For this I think the ideal step is `MySQL Bulk Loader` step which is listed under Bulk loading section. Along with that use the said

```
useServerPrepStmts=false
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
useCompression=true
```

in JDBC options in the connection.
These useCompression will compress the traffic between the client and the MySQL server
where as other two will form `INSERT INTO tbl (a,b) VALUES (1,'x'),(2,'y'),(3,'z');` without using separate insert statements for each.

Comment: Unfortunately, my development machine is a Windows Server 2012 R2, so I'm getting [this error](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-2756).

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Increase the RAM Size for PDI a.k.a Spoon.
2. Using the Command line utility such as ( Kitchen or Pan) run your Job or Transformation.

Well Now compare the speed.

Cheers!